# Why would a prepared statement work using get_result but not when binding the results?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am having to change over from using get_result() to bind_result() and it is causing a lot of issues. With get_result the query works perfectly! I have LITERALLY seen this go from working one second to not working the next with one change to the code, removing `echo $joinid` and even have one page that the query fails halfway through a while loop and only returns 2 of 4 known results before throwing the bind param error.

And I always get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in

For instance The following when I use get_result()works fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, auction_title, auction_date, auction_time, auction_address, auction_city, auction_state, auction_zipcode, description FROM auctions WHERE join_id = ?";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$row['join_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Though this fails.

*NOTE:$joinid comes from another query and echos out to what it should.*

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id, auction_title, auction_date, auction_time, auction_address, auction_city, auction_state, auction_zipcode, description FROM auctions WHERE join_id = ?";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$joinid);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $auction_title, $auction_date, $auction_time, $auction_address, $auction_city, $auction_state, $auction_zipcode, $description);
```

Here is the var_dump with a side by side comparison, different query but same results overall:

```
$sql = "SELECT join_id, bus_name, first_name, last_name, address, city, state, zip, phone, fax, email, wsaddr, image_name, bio FROM auctioneer WHERE id = ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$getVar);
$stmt->execute();
//$results = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->bind_result($join_id, $bus_name, $first_name, $last_name, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $fax, $email, $wsaddr, $image_name, $bio);
var_dump($stmt);
//$stmt->close();
```

Using get_result:
`object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(14) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }`

Using bind_result:
`object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(14) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }`

Comment: you got a boolean, so something failed. check `mysqli_error()` for the reason. Plus, unless you've enabled exceptions. ALWAYS check for `false` returns - never assume success when dealing with a database, or any other external resource.

Comment: I have done that, when using get_result a var_dump of $stmt returns successful, with bind_result it returns -1 with nothing changed but the removal of get_result and the addition of bind_result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might come along looking for it later, in my case the correct answer was adding `store_result()`.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, auction_title, auction_date, auction_time, auction_address, auction_city, auction_state, auction_zipcode, description FROM auctions WHERE join_id = ?";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$join_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $auction_title, $auction_date, $auction_time, $auction_address, $auction_city, $auction_state, $auction_zipcode, $description);
```

Comment: FROM THE MANUAL: You must call mysqli_stmt_store_result() for every query that successfully produces a result set (SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN), if and only if you want to buffer the complete result set by the client, so that the subsequent mysqli_stmt_fetch() call returns buffered data.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_stmt::bind_result` just tells the `mysqli` extension where to put values when data is retrieved from the query, **it does not actually get the next row from the result set**, you have to do that with a `$stmt->fetch()`

So

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id, auction_title, auction_date, auction_time, 
                auction_address, auction_city, auction_state, 
                auction_zipcode, description 
         FROM auctions 
         WHERE join_id = ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$joinid);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $auction_title, $auction_date, $auction_time, 
                   $auction_address, $auction_city, $auction_state, 
                   $auction_zipcode, $description);
$stmt->fetch();   // this actually fills the bound variables
echo $id;  // etc
```

Comment: it was done further down the page and not included... and I am pretty sure that wouldn't cause a bind_result error....